# Adding image next to a Title Header in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a UITableView using Group-style. I only have a single group in my table.

Here are my two questions:

1) How do I display a picture next to my title in the top header? Basically I would like to put the logo of our company next to that title.

2) Can I change the background color (I don't like the grey one) in the header and can I adjust the height of that header?

Answer (score 0):

Just return a custom view to your header this way:

```
    //Draws a custom view for the header instructions
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*) tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    if ([tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] != 0) // To handle nil entries
    {
    UIView* headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 60)] autorelease];

         // set up whatever view you want here. E.g.

    UILabel* headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, headerView.frame.size.width - 20.0, headerView.frame.size.height)];

        headerLabel.text = @"Tap items in the list to pin them.\nTap the Remix button to clear all unpinned items";
        headerLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    headerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt" size: 14];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:kColorRed green:kColorGreen blue:kColorBlue alpha:1];
    headerLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        headerLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [headerView setTag:010];
    [headerView setAlpha:1];

    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];
    [headerLabel release];
    return headerView;
    }
    else {
        return nil;    // again to handle nil tables. You should be nice and at least show an error label on the view.
    }    
}
```

And this gives you something like this:

[image: How it should only work]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I did implement the method but my program crashed. I am using ARC hence I removed all the autorealease

Comment: Well hope that it did work fine afterwards. If you found the solution to your question make sure to tick the checkmark!